How to plot sympy functions with units
I am trying to create a 3d plot with sympy that has units, but I am getting different errors depending on where I try to type the units in. Below the units are built in the function itself, but I get an error also if I type the units into the plot axis variable: (a, 2.*meter/second^2., 0.*meter/second^2.), etc.
I plunged through the Sympy documentation and couldn't find anything on plotting with units.
Is there an established way to do this?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy.physics.units.systems.si import SI
from sympy.physics.units import second, newton, meter, kilogram
from sympy import init_printing
from sympy import *
from IPython.display import display
from sympy.plotting import plot3d

F, m, a = symbols('F_ m_ a_')

def F(a,m):
    return a*(meter/second**2.)*m*kilogram

plot3d(F(a,m), (a, 2.,0.), (m, 0.,1.), zlabel=S('F_'))

I tried to use plot3d in sympy to plot a function with units, but it didn't work. I get either TypeError: Cannot convert the expression to float OR TypeError: cannot determine the truth value of Relational

Generally, you can't plot a symbolic expression containing units. Here is why.
When you create your expression with F(a,m), a and m are symbols. However, the expression also contains other entities, kilogram, meter, second, which are instances of Quantity (from sympy.physics.units).
When you execute plot3d(F(a,m), (a, 2.,0.), (m, 0.,1.)), this is what happens:

F(a,m) generates a symbolic expression: kilogram*meter*a_*m_/second**2
The plotting module uses lambdify to convert that symbolic expression to a numerical function: f = lambdify([a, m], F(a,m)). Let's look at it:
help(f)

Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(a_, m_)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:

    func(a_, m_)

    Expression:

    kilogram*meter*a_*m_/second**2

    Source code:

    def _lambdifygenerated(a_, m_):
        return kilogram*meter*a_*m_/second**2

The numerical function has two parameters, a_, m_, but it doesn't know what kilogram, meter, second are.
The plotting module generates numerical array for a_, m_, provides them to the numerical function. At evaluation, you get those errors.

Possible solution: remove the units from the symbolic expression. You can either rewrite your expression without units, or you can remove them with a substitution. Here is how:
from sympy.physics.units import Quantity
expr_with_units = F(a, m)
# create a substitution dictionary: replace each quantity with number 1
sd = {k: 1 for k in expr_with_units.find(Quantity)}
expr_without_units = expr_with_units.subs(sd)

plot3d(expr_without_units, (a, 0, 2), (m, 0, 1), zlabel=r"$kg \cdot m / s^2$")



That is what I was concerned about. Any ideas how to keep track on the units with more complex equations containing more units? Or do I just have to keep track on them manually? I am transitioning from MathCad to Python and I would be happy to have similar platform on python that can automatically keep track on the units. Manually it is too easy to have wrong units like kgmm instead of kgm. Thanks for your example and reply.

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve. My last attempt to use sympy's units was 4-5 years ago, and I was trying to achieve the same thing. Back then the situation was terrible, so much so that I haven't looked at it ever since, but I don't think the situation have improved that much. Moreover, SymPy is coded in such a way that it is not possible to assign units to symbols :( . sympy.physics.units is one of those module where I always asked myself what goal were the developers trying to achieve... Never figured it out...
